# SQLITE: Get Current time in millis and fit into 32 bit int

Tags: sqlite

I need a 32 bit time identifier. At the moment in sqlite `strftime('%s','now')` is being used in a trigger to set a 32 bit time identifier. Turns out a resolution of one a second doesn't cut it for our application so I want to move to milliseconds and cut off the left side bits to retain 32 bits in total. I don't need to be able to use the result as a datetime any more as it will be concatenated into an identifier. The string doesn't need to be 32 bit, the number it represents however must be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution using bitshift on 64 bit systems:

get the time in millis with

```
cast(julianday("now")*100000000 as int)
```

then bitshift this number left 32 times then right the same number of times. This drops the leading bits. Then take the absolute value.

```
abs((cast(julianday("now")*100000000 as int) << 32) >> 32)
```

and voila!

Answer (score 0):

With 32 bits, you get 2<sup>32</sup> = 4294967296 distinct values.

4294967296 milliseconds is just 49.7 days.

If your application blows up after 49 days, you're [not alone](https://serverfault.com/a/37334), but in any case it's not a good idea.

Even using seconds for the time since 1970 [is going to run out soon with 32 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).
You can use a different epoch (e.g., 2015-01-01, or even 2020-01-01 and start with negative numbers), but you need to reduce the precision to be able to get a usable range out of 32 bits.

Comment: No it's not a problem. The db lives only as long as each run and each run takes a few hours at the longest. Good comment but not really an answer. I found a solution after coming home from holidays.